# Elegant "select distinct" for collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am fairly new to RoR and hacking on a small application. In order to display existing values of some model column in a form, I currently do:

```
<% form_for([@testbox, @testitem]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :sortkey %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :sortkey, Testitem.groups , :sortkey, :sortkey, {:include_blank => true}  %>
<% end %>
```

In the model `Testitem` I have:

```
def Testitem.groups
  return find_by_sql("SELECT DISTINCT sortkey from testitems; ")
end
```

I am sure there is a more elegant solution to this? I have tried `find(:all).sortkey.unique` but that throws `undefined method 'sortkey' for #<Array:0x59d1b60>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This accomplishes the same thing but I'm not sure it's any more elegant:

```
Testitem.find(:all, :select => "DISTINCT sortkey")
```

Comment: +1 for that, it's at least more elegant as I don't have to write a complete SQL statement. Let's see if there is something even better.

Comment: plus +1 yes!  
It's in the model - which is always better than the controller (solution below). The reasons are many but are summed up in 'fat model', 'thin controller'.  
It also returns less records at the start from the database which is always good.
It's much more readable - :select => "DISTINCT sortkey" (pretty close to English - 'Select the distinct sortkeys') is a heck of a lot more readable and maintainable then .map(&:sortkey).uniq  IMHO

Answer (score 1):

It's probably much faster to do it Patrick Robertson's way.  You can also do it with the `group` option:

```
Testitem.find(:all, :group => "sortkey")
```

using the `:select` option will put the `DISTICT sortkey` into the SQL query, while using `:group` adds `GROUP BY sortkey`.  I don't know which one is faster.

You could also do it by just returning the strings of `sortkey` as well:

```
Testitem.find(:all).map(&:sortkey).uniq
```

This is probably slower because it will retrieve all the items and do the filtering on the Ruby side instead of the SQL side.